# Why does the order of variables in an equation matter compared to reduction or addition?

Tags: calculus

Some things in live are just obvious and we have to take them for granted, just like that 1+1 is (almost) always equal to 2. Yet, I sometimes wonder behind some simple mechanics, such as the following.

In any addition equation, where we increase either X or Y, such as X+Y or X * Y, the order of the variables is irrelevant. Both 7+3 and 3+7 make 10.

Reductions, however, the order *is* relevant; for such 7-3=4 and 3-7 = -4

Many explanatory videos, such as [Zero is still One (Factorial)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Mfk_L4Nx2ZI) and
[Russel's Paradox](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xauCQpnbNAM), often fascinate me and I was hoping for some thoughts about the above. Is it something we, indeed, have to take for granted or has some smart mind ever thought why this is, the way it is?

Comment: Some operations are [commutative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) and some are not. Nothing paradoxically here.

Comment: I don't understand your question.  You can tell that $7-3\neq 3-7$.  Is that not reason enough for you that subtraction is not commutative (*i.e. that changing the order can change the result*)?  Why should you have expected otherwise?  Just because addition and multiplication are commutative?  If you put on your socks before your shoes, your feet are rather comfortable.  If you put on your shoes before your socks... you'll likely rip your socks.

Comment: [Commutativity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commutative_property) means that $\text{Op}(a,b)=\text {Op}(b,a)$. In layman terms: you can switch the positions of the "operands" and the result of the operation $\text{Op}$ does not change: e.g. addition.

Comment: Perhaps, you would be able to appreciate how subtraction is *defined*.  Subtraction is just addition of an additive inverse.  We define $x - y$ as $x + (-y)$ where $-y$ is the additive inverse of $y$.  That is... $7-3 = 7+(-3)$ while $3-7$ is $3+(-7)$.  It is not symmetrical.  We only replace the number on the right with their additive inverse.

Comment: If we assume $a-b=b-a$ , we can conclude (by adding $a+b$) : $2a=2b$ which implies $a=b$. Hence only in the case the numbers are equal, the order does not matter (which is no surprise). We can also see this by multiplying $a-b>0$ with $-1$, which leads to $b-a<0$ showing that $a-b=b-a$ is impossible and analogue we can do it for the case $a-b<0$

Comment: Well, subtraction *is* commutative in those rare, but interesting cases where $1+1$ is not $2$, but $0$.